# Any way to transfer Strings over NFC?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

I'm currently making an app, and I need to send some strings to a reader via NFC, is this possible with current limitations? I know that Swift 4.0 includes CoreNFC, but that only includes reading, not writing.

Answer (score 2):

Its only for Reading  via CoreNFC framework (iOS 11.0+), Reading NFC NDEF tags is supported on iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus.
 Detect NFC tags and read messages that contain NDEF data. Using NDEF Messages  will get identifier, payload, type, typeNameFormat.

Comment: Are you sure you can transfer file(image/pdf) using NFC ?